# Does Blender have something like the Hidden Line mode?

Tags: blender

Is there something in the `Viewport` Blender modes like 3D Max's `Hidden Line` - analogous to `Wireframe`, but with hidden invisible faces behind other polygons?

Answer (score 1):

In blender, wireframe shading will always draw all edges.

With solid shading, in object mode only the visible faces are drawn, while in edit mode there is an option to show/hide the hidden wireframe.

[image: show or hide hidden wireframe]

Comment: What should if I don't see that option in edit mode?

Comment: @Koning It only shows for mesh objects. It also doesn't show if you are using wireframe or boundbox for viewport shading.